# Existence of positive integers $a_1,a_2,...,a_k$

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math

Let $x$ and $y$ be positive integers such that $\arctan(\frac1x)+\arctan(\frac1y)<\frac{\pi}2$.

Show that there exists positive integers $a_1,a_2,...,a_k$ none of which equals $x$ or $y$ such that $\arctan(\frac1x)+\arctan(\frac1y)+\arctan(\frac1{a_1})+\arctan(\frac1{a_2})+...+\arctan(\frac1{a_k})=\frac{\pi}2$.

I simplified the given inequality to $\arctan(\frac{\frac1x+\frac1y}{1-\frac1{xy}})<\frac{\pi}2$ but i can find what to do next. Can anyone guide me to the solution?

Answer (score 0):

An easier variant of [RMM 2009 P4](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h263024p1428739).

I will prove a stronger statement - the RMM problem itself.

It generalizes the two integers $x,y$ to a set of positive integers.

This solution is similar to the solution presented in the link.

First, for convenience, we define $f(x)=\arctan x$.

Also, for a set $X$, we define $g(X)=\sum_{x \in X} f(\frac{1}{x})$.

Now, say we are given a set $X$, where $g(X)=f(\frac{a}{b}) < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $(a,b)=1$.

It suffices to find a set $Y$, such that $X \cap Y = \emptyset$ and $g(Y)=f(\frac{b}{a})$, since we will have $$g(X \cup Y)=g(X)+g(Y)=f(\frac{a}{b})+f(\frac{b}{a})=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Disregard the fact that we need distinct positive integers, for now.

Now if $b=1$, we are done since we can just let $Y=\{a\}$ to finish the problem.

Assume that $b \ge 2$. Now set an integer $l \in Y$ which will be determined later.

We have $$g(Y-\{l\})=g(Y)-f(\frac{1}{l}) = f(\frac{b}{a})-f(\frac{1}{l})=f(\frac{bl-a}{al+b})$$
We want $0<bl-a<b$, which motivates us to set $l=1+\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \rfloor$, since $a$ cannot be a divisor of $b$.

Now the numerator strictly decreases, since $\frac{a}{b}<l<1+\frac{a}{b}$. Therefore, after performing this finitely, we will have the numerator equal to $1$, i.e. $b=1$, a case we already had a look on.

*NOTE: If this is uncomfortable, use strong induction on the numerator.*

> The base case $b=1$ is the same.
>
> Assume that there is a set $P$ such that $g(P)=f(\frac{x}{y})$ if
>   $x<b$.
>
> Since $0<bl-a<b$, by induction hypothesis, we have a set $P$ such that
>   $g(P)=f(\frac{bl-a}{al+b})$.
>
> Add the number $l$ to find $g(P \cup \{l\})=f(\frac{b}{a})$, which
>   completes the induction.

We have determined set $Y$, but we don't know that it has a repeating number.

Perform the map $t \mapsto \{t+1,t^2+t+1\}$ on the elements of $Y$.

Since the functions $p(x)=x+1$ and $q(x)=x^2+x+1$ are not bounded above, we can perform it finitely to replace the repeating numbers.

To make this argument more rigorous, order the elements by size and start from the smallest number. When encountered with a repeating number(s), keep performing the map on the resulting numbers until the numbers that result from this map are larger than any other element.

Since the number of the elements of the original set is finite, the number of times that this map needs to be used is finite as well, so the resulting set is finite. We are done. $\blacksquare$